# Java: How to use microphone input as input for the JavaFX media player?

Tags: java, javafx, media, javasound

I want to play the microphone input in realtime using the JavaFX media player (to analyse its frequencies). The problem is, that the MediaPlayer only accepts Strings as source. I know how to write the microphone input into a byte array and into a file.

Using the byte array as source for the MediaPlayer is (for me) not possible. I tried using a temporary file, but that causes the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Empty signature!
```

I think this is, because I'm using a file as input while I'm still writing new data into it. My full code until now:

```
public class Music {

static AudioFormat format;
static DataLine.Info info;

public static void input(int i, int j, int pinState) {
    format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);

    try {
        info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        final TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        targetLine.open();

        AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(targetLine);

        File temp = File.createTempFile("Input", ".wav");
        temp.deleteOnExit();

        Thread targetThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                targetLine.start();
                try {
                    AudioSystem.write(audioStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, temp);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        targetThread.start();

        Media media = new Media(temp.toURI().toURL().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        player.setAudioSpectrumThreshold(-100);
        player.setMute(false);
        player.setAudioSpectrumListener(new AudioSpectrumListener() {
             @Override  
             public void spectrumDataUpdate(double timestamp, double duration, float[] magnitudes, float[] phases) {
                 if(Var.nodeController[i] == 3) { //testing if the targetLine should keep on capturing sound
                 } else {
                     targetLine.stop();
                     targetLine.close();
                     player.stop();
                 }
             }
        });
        player.play();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I need to find a solution to use the microphone input as MediaPlayer input, either using a file or a byte array or any other possible solution.

Comment: JavaFX [supports](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedProtocols) live streaming with HTTP(S). I suppose you could open a connection and stream it that way. But as I've never used HLS I have no idea how, if possible, to do this (or if it's even a good idea).

Comment: I'll check that out, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to speculate that the following library might be helpful.
https://github.com/SzymonKatra/AudioAnalyzer

Note that it makes use of [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) which claims to be:

> A complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream
>   audio and video.

The key component (based on my cursory look-over) seems to be the class [FFTAnalyzer.java](https://github.com/SzymonKatra/AudioAnalyzer/blob/master/src/audioanalyzer/logic/analyzers/FFTAnalyzer.java) which the documentation says is based upon an FFT code/algorithm from [Princeton](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/InplaceFFT.java.html).

So, the basic plan (I believe) would be the following:

1. obtain microphone input (a stream of bytes) from targetdataline
2. convert N frames of bytes to normalized floats or doubles and package as an array to send to FFTAnalyzer.analyze(double[] samples)
3. request the analysis results via FFTAnalyzer.getAmplitudes()
4. examine the result for each equalization band and apply smoothing as appropriate
5. repeat

I'm unclear as to exactly how much of the library is needed. It could be that since you are not dealing with video or cross-platform issues, only a class or two from this library would be needed.

Comment: That's a solution using FFT, which I tried to avoid by using the AudioSpectrumListener of the MediaPlayer. For FFT I already asked another question.

Comment: While looking over the specs on the JavaFX MediaPlayer, it became clear that the only streaming input it accepts is HTML HLS (slaw's comment). While looking at a way to convert, I came across an app using FFmpeg. It might be possible to use FFmpeg to convert your microphone input to a video format readable by MediaPlayer, but this felt kind of dubious to me compared to using the FFT library that the app made use of. I guess I omitted a couple steps in my thinking when I put up this answer.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, but I just asked this question to avoid implementing FFT in my code. But while trying to use the Media player I already found a solution with FFT, so I wont need the Media player anymore. Nevertheless thanks for your answer! I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: And now others who come here and that would like to have the microphone input in mediaplayer with FFT, but who would like to avoid the need to install ffmpeg don't know what you found and need to search further. Why didn't you post (a link to) the solution you found? You can also use stackoveflow to help others and not only to get help for yourself ...